# convert lists of values in a string, separated by two different delimiters, into separate rows

Tags: r, string, data.table

I have a `data.table` (`dt`) which looks like this

```
#    id               value
# 1:  1      {1:3.2,2:14.2}
# 2:  2      {1:14.0,2:3.0}
# 3:  3 {1:3.4,2:3.9,3:0.1}
# 4:  4             {1:2.1}
```

The `value` column comprises lists of values, where each one is introduced by its position in the list (1,2,3...) followed by a `:`, then the value itself.  list values are separated by commas, and the whole list is enclosed in braces `{...}`.

I want to convert this to a long format (`dt.all`) like

```
#    id N value
# 1:  1 1   3.2
# 2:  1 2  14.2
# 3:  2 1  14.0
# 4:  2 2   3.0
# 5:  3 1   3.4
# 6:  3 2   3.9
# 7:  3 3   0.1
# 8:  4 1   2.1
```

Various failed attempts include:

```
stingr::str_extract(string = dt$value, pattern = "(?<=:).*(?=,)")
gsub(".*: *(.*?) *,.*", "\\1", dt$value)
gsubfn:strapplyc(dt$value, ":(.*?),", simplify = c)
```

Any suggestions on a neat way to do this?  `data.table` solutions preferred, but failing that will accept tidyverse or other methods.

**The data:**

```
dt = structure(list(id = 1:4, value = c("{1:3.2,2:14.2}", "{1:14.0,2:3.0}", 
  "{1:3.4,2:3.9,3:0.1}", "{1:2.1}")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("data.table", 
    "data.frame"))

dt.all = structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L), N = c(1L, 
  2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L), value = c(3.2, 14.2, 14, 3, 3.4, 
    3.9, 0.1, 2.1)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("data.table", 
      "data.frame"))
```

Comment: @Rui This particular format may allow different approaches, like fromJSON posted by the OP as an answer below, so I don't think it is a dupe.

Comment: @Frank Yes, I realized that. That's why I didn't close as dupe, it deserved to be answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found that if I use `gsub` to wrap the item numbers in quotes, then I can parse these as `json` expressions using `library(jsonlite)`.

```
dt[, .(value = {v1 <- unlist(fromJSON(gsub("([0-9]+):", '"\\1":', value)))}, 
       N = names(v1)),by=id]

#    id value N
# 1:  1   3.2 1
# 2:  1  14.2 2
# 3:  2  14.0 1
# 4:  2   3.0 2
# 5:  3   3.4 1
# 6:  3   3.9 2
# 7:  3   0.1 3
# 8:  4   2.1 1
```

Answer (score 4):

One way using `tidyverse` functions can be to remove quotes (`{}`) from the string, use `str_extract_all` to get number before and after colon (`:`) and `unnest` those values.

```
library(dplyr)

dt %>%
  mutate(value = gsub("\\{|\\}", "", value), 
         N = stringr::str_extract_all(value, "\\d+(?=:)"), 
         value = stringr::str_extract_all(value, "(?<=:)\\d+\\.\\d+")) %>%
  tidyr::unnest(N, value)

#  id N value
#1  1 1   3.2
#2  1 2  14.2
#3  2 1  14.0
#4  2 2   3.0
#5  3 1   3.4
#6  3 2   3.9
#7  3 3   0.1
#8  4 1   2.1
```

Answer (score 4):

We can use `separate_rows`.  We split the 'value' column based on delimiters with `separate_rows`, then `filter` out the rows that are not needed and `group_by`, 'id', create a sequence column while extracting the numeric part from 'value'

```
library(tidyverse)
dt %>% 
   separate_rows(value, sep="[{}:]") %>% 
   group_by(id) %>%
   filter(value != "") %>%
   slice(-1) %>%
   mutate(N = row_number(), value = readr::parse_number(value))
# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   id [4]
#     id value     N
#  <int> <dbl> <int>
#1     1  3.22     1
#2     1 14.2      2
#3     2 14.0      1
#4     2  3        2
#5     3  3.42     1
#6     3  3.93     2
#7     3  0.1      3
#8     4  2.1      1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
ans <- dt[, {
    parts <- strsplit(gsub("\\{|\\}", "", value), ",|:")
    c(.(id=unlist(mapply(rep, id, lengths(parts)/2))), 
        as.data.table(matrix(unlist(parts), byrow=TRUE, ncol=2L)))
}]
setnames(ans, c("V1","V2"), c("N","value"))[]
```

output:

```
   id N value
1:  1 1   3.2
2:  1 2  14.2
3:  2 1  14.0
4:  2 2   3.0
5:  3 1   3.4
6:  3 2   3.9
7:  3 3   0.1
8:  4 1   2.1
```

Timing code:

```
library(data.table)
library(jsonlite)
DT <- data.table(id=1:1e6,
    value = c("{1:3.2,2:14.2}", "{1:14.0,2:3.0}", "{1:3.4,2:3.9,3:0.1}", "{1:2.1}"))

mtd0 <- function() {
    DT[, .(value = {v1 <- unlist(fromJSON(gsub("([0-9]+):", '"\\1":', value)))},
        N = names(v1)),by=id]
}

mtd1 <- function() {
    ans <- DT[, {
        parts <- strsplit(gsub("\\{|\\}", "", value), ",|:")
        c(.(id=unlist(mapply(rep, id, lengths(parts)/2))),
            as.data.table(matrix(unlist(parts), byrow=TRUE, ncol=2L)))
    }]
    setnames(ans, c("V1","V2"), c("N","value"))
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(mtd0(), mtd1(), times=3L)
```

timings:

```
Unit: seconds
   expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
 mtd0() 69.976046 70.196980 71.375693 70.417914 72.075517 73.733119     3   b
 mtd1()  3.659296  3.687167  4.139271  3.715038  4.379259  5.043479     3  a
```